# angular binding json data if field match

Tags: angularjs, json

I have 3 JSON files and want to fetch the data if some `id/field` matches with the other JSON.

```
<li ng-repeat="event in eventPoints">
    {{event.tripid}} , {{event.eventid}} -- ,{{event.seconds_offset}}, {{cleanPoints[event.seconds_offset].lat}}, {{cleanPoints[event.eventid].lon}} , {{trips[event.tripid].tripname}}
</li>
```

Here is the [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/TnvQcRH89lkPdgV84AXZ?p=preview).

I want to get tripname of 2011, because the 2011 is tripid of other two json files.

Comment: Can you eleborate? It's a bit unclear what you are asking.

Comment: you have an invalid json in the plunker `trips.json` `"tripname":Mount` should be in double quotes.

Comment: so what if two `ids/field` match in the other json?

Comment: I want to get the value by property. Suppose i want "eventid":"12" data from eventPoints.json for this event id i want longitude and latitude but its not there in the eventPoints so i am taking the "seconds_offset":"511" data from cleanPoints. because seconds_offeset is there in both files

Comment: ok what I'm asking is that `seconds_offset` can be the same in more than one trips how can you know which one to grab?

Comment: even better can you describe in your question the relations between the json files as if it was database tables?